# How do you change the background on TextBlock on press or on click?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, textblock

I am able to get a TextBlock in XAML to have an IsMouseOver trigger, but what about an IsPressed or IsFocused. I want the TextBlock background to change color when the user clicks on the TextBlock. This is TextBlock NOT a TextBox.  It there a way to do it in only XAML.

I tried:

```
   <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>

     </Trigger>
     <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>

      </Trigger>
```

And these don't seem to work at all.  Is there another property or is it even possible to do on a TextBlock.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some options = A button with the content bound to a TextBlock. Or an initially transparent button laying over top of the TextBlock and just edit your button template accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a `ToggleButton`, change `ToggleButton.Template` to a lone `ContentPresenter` in a `Border`. Hook up `Background` to `Border.Background` via `TemplateBinding`.

This gives you `IsChecked` to trigger on and just shows text with a background color.